# Past or Passed Used in a Sentence

Tags: word-choice

Which sentence is correct:  Do you have any recollection of the time period that passed while this was going on?  Or, Do you have any recollection of the time period that past while this was going on?

Comment: Please include the research you’ve done. I'm not sure that your question suits our English Language Learners site better. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic.

Answer (score 2):

"past" is a noun referring to previous time. "passed" is a form of the verb "pass". Since "the time period that ____ " calls for a verb (the time period is the subject of the verb), the correct word is "passed".

Answer (score 1):

Grammatically, it should be "passed" since "period that ____ while" suggests a verb.

The phrasing still feels out of place, I would go with something like:

> Do you have any recollection of the time during which this occurred?